# Moving exoplayer controller above nav bar

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a fullscreen video, with a translucent nav bar over the video.
Example here:

[image: Edge to edge android transparent nav bar]

Now the nav bar overlaps the player controller so I just need to move it up.
I moved the controller up by including it in my activity layout file right next to the PlayerView:

```
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/activity_my_activity_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
        android:id="@+id/activity_my_activity_player_control_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then I adjusted the code:

```
//get the player controller
playerControlView = findViewById(R.id.activity_my_activity_player_control_view);

//get the player view
playerView = findViewById(R.id.activity_my_activity_video);

//create the player
player = ExoPlayerFactory.getInstance().buildExoPlayer(this);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_OFF);
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl));
player.prepare();

//set the player in the views
playerControlView.setPlayer(player);
playerView.setPlayer(player);
```

The behavior is that the "activity_my_activity_player_control_view" controller shows briefly and then disappears after the activity is created.  This controller does not appear again when one touches the PlayerView

Instead the built in controller is the one that responds to the touches of playerview by appearing and disappearing.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was following the information found here:
https://exoplayer.dev/ui-components.html

Unfortunately I must have misunderstood or the article wasn't clear enough (I'm voting for the former).

Anyway since all I want to do is change the position, I found the easiest way was to just get a reference to the default controller in PlayerView by using:

```
findViewById(R.id.exo_controller)
```

And then after that I was able to adjust margins etc to put it above the nav bar.